# Import calendar 0's

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

When I import calendar in python and run this code I don't know why it generates 0s:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> c = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.Sunday)
>>> for i in c.itermonthdays(2025, 4):
        print (i)
```

It gives strange result...the zeroes in the beginning and at the end.

[image]

Comment: For your future reference, please ensure the code in your question is compilable. It's also better to copy and paste the output of your code instead of a screenshot if possible.

Comment: @giusti : I copied the output first but it said your question is almost code and I couldn't post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs for [`itermonthdates`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.itermonthdates):

> This iterator will return all days (as `datetime.date` objects) for the
>   month and all days before the start of the month or after the end of
>   the month that are required to get a complete week.

[`itermonthdays`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.itermonthdays) uses the same system:

> Days returned will simply be day of the month numbers. For the days
>   outside of the specified month, the day number is 0.

April 2025 [starts on a Tuesday](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/monthly.html?year=2025&month=4), so the first two days of the first week are not in April, nor are the last three days of the last week.

Comment: If all you want is the numbers, you could get `range(1, calendar.monthrange(2025, 4)[1])` instead

Comment: It's only printing the numbers upto 29 https://repl.it/repls/DraftyPopularProcedurallanguage

Comment: @Python03 My bad, you would have to add one: `range(1, calendar.monthrange(2025, 4)[1]+1)`

Comment: This helped me a lot